# Exposing the regeneratorRuntime to jest, in a typescript project

Tags: typescript, babeljs, jestjs

I'm trying to setup jest for a typescript project. I'm having trouble configuring my project so that I can test generators.

I have the following simplified test case

```
// my.test.ts    
import * as expect from 'expect';

function* testGenerator() {
  return true;
}

describe('testcase', () => {
  it('should see the regeneratorRuntime', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Because I'm using typescript, I've configured Jest to user a preprocessing script that first compiles the typescript to javascript, and then use babel to transform the output. My jest config looks like this.

```
// package.json   
...     
  "jest": {
        "transform": {
          ".(ts|tsx)": "<rootDir>/internals/scripts/jestPreprocessor.js"
        },
        "testMatch": [
          "**/*.test.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)"
        ],
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
          "ts",
          "tsx",
          "js",
          "jsx"
        ]   }, ...
```

And my jest preprocessor looks like this (which I [found here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1466#issuecomment-269421820))

```
const tsc = require('typescript');
const tsConfig = require('../../tsconfig.json');
const babelJest = require('babel-jest')

module.exports = {
    process(src, path) {
        const isTs = path.endsWith('.ts');
        const isTsx = path.endsWith('.tsx');
        if (isTs || isTsx) {
            src = tsc.transpileModule(src, tsConfig);
            src = src.outputText;
            // update the path so babel can try and process the output
            path = path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf('.')) + (isTs ? '.js' : '.jsx') || path;
        }

        if (path.endsWith('.js') || path.endsWith('.jsx')) {
            src = babelJest.process(src, path);
        }
        return src;
    },
};
```

It's pretty straight forward as far as I can tell. It's transpiling the Typescript to javascript, then changing the file extension to `js` so that babel can parse it, and then it passes the src to babel-jest.

So that just leaves the babel config, which looks like this (in package.json)...

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      ["env", {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            "Chrome >= 52",
            "FireFox >= 44",
            "Safari >= 7",
            "Explorer 11",
            "last 4 Edge versions"
          ]
        },
        "debug": true
      }]
    ],
    "env": {
      "production": {
        "only": [
          "app"
        ],
        "plugins": [
          "transform-react-remove-prop-types",
          "transform-react-constant-elements",
          "transform-react-inline-elements"
        ]
      },
      "test": {
        "plugins": [
          "istanbul"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

I'm using the `babel-preset-env` plugin to manage plugins and polyfills for the environments I'm targeting.

If I run the tests I get the following error

`ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`

But I can see that the 'transfrom-regenerator' plugin is being included because of the debugging output from `babel-preset-env`

However, if I add `"exclude": ["transfrom-regenerator"]` to the babel-preset-env config like this

```
["env", {
    "targets": {
        "browsers": [
            "Chrome >= 52",
            "FireFox >= 44",
            "Safari >= 7",
            "Explorer 11",
            "last 4 Edge versions"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": ["transform-regenerator"],
    "debug": true
}]
```

My tests run and I don't get the error. Which is fine for testing, but not good for IE11.

What I can't figure out is why including the `transform-regenerator` plugin causes the `regeneratorRuntime` error in Jest. I'm suspecting some sort of conflict with the code the TypeScript compiler outputs, but I cant track it down.

Comment: Just so you know, the most recent version of typescript support generators without involving Babel. Specify `--downlevelIteration` into TypeScript 2.3 or greater to enable